# Symfony "No route found for "GET /check.php" fresh install

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-404, symfony-2.7

I've just installed Symfony 2.7.

I've started my app from the command line with:

```
$ php app/console server:run
```

I installed XAMPP to run PHP.

The following pictures show my **localhost:8000/config.php** and **localhost:8000** pages.

Config
[image]!
Main page
[image]!

**EXACT SOLUTION:**

```
_blog:
    path:       /
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
```

Where:

- **path** points to localhost:8000
- **defults**: executes the **indexAction** method in the file **"blog\src\AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php"** (the file was in my project's file system by default, so for a different controller, replace this file to to your own)

Comment: What about `localhost:8000` ? Can we see your routing files?

Comment: localhost:8000 says the same as localhost:8000/blog, what files should I include (routing files) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fresh install of symfony does not have any routes.  In your bundle you'll need to define the route for /blog.

The file at /app/config/routing.yml should look something like this.

```
my_bundle:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

This will ensure the routes you setup in your bundles config are included.

So in /src/MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml you should have something like

```
my_blog:
    path: /blog
    defaults:
        _controller: MyBundle:Blog:index
```

Running `php app/console router:debug` in your command line will also show you your available routes.

Don't forget to flush your cache too `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod` or `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev` for the dev environment.

Give this a good read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Strange that it doesn't have a route even for a test page. And the article is way too complex. Anyways, I've made it happen, so thanks for your help.